# bullet image position

Tags: position, bulletedlist

I am having problem in positioning the bullet in menu.

I am using custom image as bullet. But bullet image is aligned with the bottom of the text. So when I am trying to align the `li` text at the center of the menu_bar `div`, the bullet image is moving up.

How to fix that so bullet image stay at the center with the text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check out css vertical-align property or make the bullet part of the whole background image for your link, without seeing an image of what you're trying to do it's difficult. Could you post an image or link to a test site?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.here is the css file

Comment: #menu_bar
{
 background:url(menu_bg.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 height:57px;
}
#menu_bar ul
{
 margin-left:50px;
 
}
#menu_bar ul li
{
 float:left;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 list-style-image:url(divider.png);
}
#menu_bar ul li a
{
 color:white;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:15px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height:57px;
 display:block;
 
}

Answer (score 0):

OK try this...

```
    #menu_bar {
/* make menu_bg.png full width of your link and add the arrow to this image */ 
background:url(menu_bg.png);  
background-repeat:repeat-x; /* remove this */
height:57px; } 

#menu_bar ul { 
margin-left:50px; 
} 

#menu_bar ul li { 
float:left; 
margin-left:10px; 
margin-right:10px; 
list-style-image:url(divider.png); /* remove this */
} 

#menu_bar ul li a { 
color:white; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
font-weight:bold; 
font-size:15px; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
line-height:57px; 
display:block; }
```